# SELECT DISTINCT on two TEXT columns slow in MySQL 5.7.20

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

A "select distinct col1,col2 from table1" where col1 and col2 are of type TEXT and table1 has about 65K rows works fine with MySQL 5.5.58. Now that I've upgraded to MySQL 5.7.20 it takes almost an hour! Does anyone know of any changes to MySQL that may be causing this? Does anyone have any suggestions how col1 and col2 should be optimally indexed for this query, or what other settings I should check to make this query run faster? I don't get the feeling that indexes are even being used since EXPLAIN says it's using a temporary table and no keys:

mysql> `

```
explain SELECT DISTINCT author,sort_author from itemsbyauthor;

+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra           |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | itemsbyauthor | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 64727 |   100.00 | Using temporary |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I don't know why there is a difference between the versions. But you can try a compound index of column prefixes like `index  (author(50), sort_author(50))`. However - I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a compound index and also separate indexes. Neither of these changed the output of EXPLAIN above nor the performance.

Comment: Ho long is the data in the columns? Run `select min(char_length(author)), avg(char_length(author)), max(char_length(author)) from itemsbyauthor`. And the same for `sort_author`.

Comment: | min(char_length(sort_author)) | avg(char_length(sort_author)) | max(char_length(sort_author)) |
|                             0 |                       30.6705 |                          3470 


| min(char_length(author)) | avg(char_length(author)) | max(char_length(author)) |

|                        0 |                  30.6705 |                     3470

Comment: I've created a table with similar stats (min/max/avg) on MariaDB 10.1.26, and it works just fine without any indexes. You can try two other queries: `SELECT author,sort_author from itemsbyauthor GROUP BY author,sort_author;` and `SELECT author,sort_author from itemsbyauthor UNION DISTINCT select '', '' from dual where 1=2` - On my system they are like 20% slower. So I guess they are executed in a different way, but return the same result. I would also look for changes in `my.ini`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to recreate the problem.Those alternate SELECT statements have the same problem (I had already tried the first, but not the second). The /etc/my.cnf are the same on both systems and are bare-bones: There is only one performance tuning parameter (innodb-buffer-pool-size = 8G) in the entire file.

Comment: I have submitted a MySQL bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89149

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, MySQL doesn't use prefix indexes properly and it seems this is one of these cases.
Do you really need the column type to be TEXT?
From the column names, it looks like the columns are holding author names, which seems like a relatively short string (let's say, up to 50 or 100 characters)?
I would re-consider the column type and try to alter it to VARCHAR with a fixed size, instead of TEXT.
Then, add a compound index that includes both columns.

Comment: See max column lengths above. I tried changing to varchars and a compound index and no help. EXPLAIN simply ignores indexes.

Comment: It's possible that MySQL doesn't see a big advantage in fetching the data from the index rather than fetching it from the disk, as there is a lot of data to fetch anyway. Can you try to FORCE the index just to check if there is any performance difference at all when using the index? try: `SELECT DISTINCT author, sort_author from itemsbyauthor FORCE INDEX (the_index_name)`

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no difference when using FORCE INDEX on a compound index. Here is an important late-breaking discovery. in MySQL 5.5 version I removed all indexes and it still runs fast! So our focus on indexes appears to be a waste of time.

Comment: If so, I would start focusing on the differences in hardware or in MySQL configuration (my.ini / my.cnf).